# Is there a way of making the following shape by CSS coding

Tags: css

Is there a way of making the following shape by CSS coding, without JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Yes more than one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by a very simple CSS code:

```css
div{
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius:50%;
border:10px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've already got it how to do it with css, same way as you did :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices :
Using **SVG** to draw your shape (The better way)

Using some **simple shapes** (circles and square) to get that
For example, a large circle blue, and inside a small circle white: You will get a circle (Else, you can get just one circle and put a blue border)
Then, two square with a 45° rotate, one at the left, and the other to the right

They are many ways like that to get this shape, but you should use svg.

Comment: I just want to stress the last part "but you should use svg"

Comment: Can you show me please how can you make this with SVG?

Comment: @John may you explain why should I avoid CSS in cases like this?

Comment: @laudbob - ease of use: SVG's "a" is specifically designed for a circular arc

Answer (score 0):

Css always provide the user the ability to design any shapes, real or unreal, especially by inventing CSS3.

Here I give you a sample that I made with css, you can have a look and get the idea, how to make yours ->

```
#moon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 3px 0px rgb(10, 56, 132);
}
```

However I am suggesting to use SVG as the others mentioned in comment, but if you need it for special case then why not.

! moon ([image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to add the alternative :) (edited to add: as inline SVG)

```
<svg height="55" width="50">
 <path d="M 45 40 A 25 25 0 0 1 5 40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" fill="none" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```